# Angular 8: Nested Reactive Form in sub-component not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular 8 Nested Reactive Form in a child component, but it does not work. I have searched the official Angular documentation, but I can not find any example on this.

My solution is available at [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyaj57?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcompany%2Fcompany.component.ts). I'm unable to show companyName for each company and address details for each address. Any ideas?

According to **Kara Ericksons talk about “Angular Forms” at the Angular Connect 2017** it should be straight forward...

Her video [Nested Forms in Angular](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/nested-forms-in-angular/) between 35:31-36:51

In **parent.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <div *ngFor="let address of addresses">
        <app-child [address]="address"></app-child>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```

In **parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  form = new FormGroup({});

  addresses : Address[] = [
    new Address("Street 1", "City 1"),
    new Address("Street 2", "City 2"),
    new Address("Street 3", "City 3"),
  ]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

In **child.component.html**

```
<div formGroupName="address">

     <input formControlName="street">
     <input formControlName="city">

</div>
```

In **child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.less']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() address: Address;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(parent: FormGroupDirective) {
    this.form = parent.form;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.addControl('address', new FormGroup({
      street: new FormControl()
      city: new FormControl()

    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing your formGroup as input instead of using the constructor into the child component.

```
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
```

instead of

```
constructor(parent: FormGroupDirective) {
  this.form = parent.form;
}
```

Edited 02/15/2020

I changed some code and solved your issue. The solution is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyaj57-kgkdih

Comment: I have have changed the implementation, too your suggestion, but I can't show the companyName in company.component.html. Any ideas? I have updated my question with my solution on stackblitz.

Comment: I updated my answer and left a stackblitz link with the solution.

Comment: Dear @bjdose, When I add `{{ companies | json }}` output at the bottom of app.component.html the output is not updating when I start filling the input boxes. Can you please explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to add parent FormGroup to viewProviders to your child component? Like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.less'],
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ParentComponent,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Yes, I did forget to add viewProviders. When is this required? Can you provide a use case? I have updated my question with my solution on stackblitz to follow @Brayan's implementation. Is this the official/recommended way of doing this?

Comment: I still can't show companyName and address details. Any ideas?